# Geocode Area Names of a City to get Lat and Long

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a list of areas names in my City and i need the Lat and Long of the same.

Is there any service which i can use the get the Data ?

I dont wanna use any map. I would like to make simple api calls and get the lat long via json or xml.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the Google Geocoding service:

REST format:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

JavaScript:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

**EDIT**: For those too lazy to read, here's the REST format example..

xml response:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Bangalore&sensor=false

json response:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bangalore&sensor=false

Comment: that requires me to use google maps. isnt there a service which i can do with just a query to its api ?

Comment: @Harsha Define `query`, define `api` and define `service`, because you are `querying` Google Geocoding `service`, using their REST or JS `api`.

Comment: something like  Http://website.com/api?place=Bangalore  not sure what its called :D

Comment: This is REST and no js required.. read the google doc I provided, its so simple...

Comment: @Harsha Are you kidding? Did you even `open` the "REST format" link Mike provided to you? http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bangalore&sensor=false

Comment: oops :D i read some place that with google maps. u need to have to map to make the call. thanks a lot. been a bit lazy to read thru i guess.

Answer (score 18):

Though the question is already answered I would like to add that google is not the only service which provides geo coding support, few main providers are listed below

**Available Solutions for the Address / ZipCode to (latitude, longitude) mapping...**

**Google API**, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ )
The **most popular** due to Google’s name. 
Extensive support available on internet (less development time).
Alas! not available freely for non-commercial usage. 
The free version has 2500 queries/day limitations. ( http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ )
Their is one clause in “Usage Terms” which says the result must be displayed in google maps, reference http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests  terms and conditions are mentioned here. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12

**Nominatium,** (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim )
A **less common organization** which provides an open source, free ware solution for the address to (latitude, longitude) mapping.
Can be also used in commercial projects.
Their are no restrictions for number of queries per day and no hidden clauses in “usage terms”.
Since the organization itself is not much popular, very less support is available.

**Yahoo API**, http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/ 
Another **popular API** like google’s but some what more available.
supports upto 50000 requests per day.
Like google extensive support is available. 
Yahoo encourages us to use the “powered by yahoo logo” but doesn’t force us for that. ( http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/api/api-2140.html )
Can be used for non-commercial purposes (I have read Yahoo Terms and doesnt find any clause which restricts us in doing that, reference http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/maps/mapsapi/mapsapi-2141.html ).

**YQL** (Yahoo Query language see:- http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ )
A SQl based query language which queries yahoo web service. for example if we have a zip code “382025” we can write a YQL as [ select centroid from geo.places where text="Enter some pin code here"].
**Yahoo encourages us to use YQL in commercial applications.** (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/ )
Most number of allowed queries as compared to all other options. (see http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/ ).
Support (?).

Comment: @HarshaMV if u liked the answer u can +1 it or can accept it as your answer......

Comment: a reason for the popularity of `Google's api` is when v search solution in google obviously it is going to give its api first... lolz